# JScrollBar should not fire events to implement a Videobar

Tags: java, swing, events, listener, jscrollbar

I try to implement a video bar. Which means I have a video and during the video is running the knob of a JScrollbar should move depending on the active video frame. I also want to use this bar as user input to move to a certain frame in the video.

So far there is a thread which polls for the active image and the active frame number. The image is displayed and the JScrollbar is set to the position represetning the frame. This works fine. (By the way I know polling is not good, but I have to do it like this because of internal silly library.)

Now I add AdjustmentListener for the user interaction. Everytime the user drags the knob of the JScrollBar I reset the position of the video. It works, too. But the problem is that the AdjustmentListener is called whenever the user drags the knob, but also when the VideoImagePollingThread is setting knob. So I have too many calls.

I can not distinguish between user events and VideoImagePollingThread events.

I tried to build my own sublcass of JScrollBar and to override

```
void fireAdjustmentValueChanged(int id, int type, int value).
```

So I do not rise events in the video thread.
But this is not working, because there is another method

```
void fireAdjustmentValueChanged(int id, int type, int value, boolean isAdjusting),
```

which is private so I can not override it.

I think this is common problem, so there must be an ideal solution.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Assuming you find yourself in a kind of loop, interrupt it by not doing anything if video position is the same as the model value.